# Trying to "encrypt" messages using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I've been trying to create something that takes a string, converts it to numbers using a switch statement, multiplies each number by the time (hours) then adds the seconds. They are supposed to go into an array and print out. This is what I have and it's not working.

```
function encrypt(time, message, password) {
  var encryptedMessage = [];
  encryptedMessage[0] = time.substring(0);
  encryptedMessage[1] = time.substring(1);
  encryptedMessage[2] = time.substring(2);
  encryptedMessage[3] = time.substring(3);
  for (var i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
    encryptedMessage[i + 4] = (getCharNumber(password.substring(i)) * time.substring(0, 1)) + time.substring(2, 3);
  }
  encryptedMessage[password.length + 4] = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
    encryptedMessage[i + password.length + 5] = (getCharNumber(message.substring(i)) * time.substring(0, 1)) + time.substring(2, 3);
  }
  return encryptedMessage;
}

function getCharNumber(char) {
  switch (char) {
    case "a":
        return "1";
        break;
    case "b":
        return "2";
        break;
    case "c":
        return "3";
        break;
    case "d":
        return "4";
        break;
    case "e":
        return "5";
        break;
    case "f":
        return "6";
        break;
    case "g":
        return "7";
        break;
    case "h":
        return "8";
        break;
    case "i":
        return "9";
        break;
    case "j":
        return "10";
        break;
    case "k":
        return "11";
        break;
    case "l":
        return "12";
        break;
    case "m":
        return "13";
        break;
    case "n":
        return "14";
        break;
    case "o":
        return "15";
        break;
    case "p":
        return "16";
        break;
    case "q":
        return "17";
        break;
    case "r":
        return "18";
        break;
    case "s":
        return "19";
        break;
    case "t":
        return "20";
        break;
    case "u":
        return "21";
        break;
    case "v":
        return "22";
        break;
    case "w":
        return "23";
        break;
    case "x":
        return "24";
        break;
    case "y":
        return "25";
        break;
    case "z":
        return "26";
        break;
    case "A":
        return "101";
        break;
    case "B":
        return "102";
        break;
    case "C":
        return "103";
        break;
    case "D":
        return "104";
        break;
    case "E":
        return "105";
        break;
    case "F":
        return "106";
        break;
    case "G":
        return "107";
        break;
    case "H":
        return "108";
        break;
    case "I":
        return "109"
        break;
    case "J":
        return "110";
        break;
    case "K":
        return "111";
        break;
    case "L":
        return "112";
        break;
    case "M":
        return "113";
        break;
    case "N":
        return "114";
        break;
    case "O":
        return "115";
        break;
    case "P":
        return "116";
        break;
    case "Q":
        return "117";
        break;
    case "R":
        return "118";
        break;
    case "S":
        return "119";
        break;
    case "T":
        return "120";
        break;
    case "U":
        return "121";
        break;
    case "V":
        return "122";
        break;
    case "W":
        return "123";
        break;
    case "X":
        return "124";
        break;
    case "Y":
        return "125";
        break;
    case "Z":
        return "126";
        break;
    case "0":
        return "200";
        break;
    case "1":
        return "201";
        break;
    case "2":
        return "202";
        break;
    case "3":
        return "203";
        break;
    case "4":
        return "204";
        break;
    case "5":
        return "205";
        break;
    case "6":
        return "206";
        break;
    case "7":
        return "207";
        break;
    case "8":
        return "208";
        break;
    case "9":
        return "209";
        break;
    case " ":
        return "300";
        break;
    case "!":
        return "301";
        break;
    case "@":
        return "302";
        break;
    case "#":
        return "303";
        break;
    case "$":
        return "304";
        break;
    case "%":
        return "305";
        break;
    case "^":
        return "306";
        break;
    case "&":
        return "307";
        break;
    case "*":
        return "308";
        break;
    case "(":
        return "309";
        break;
    case ")":
        return "310";
        break;
    case "-":
        return "311";
        break;
    case "_":
        return "312";
        break;
    case "=":
        return "313";
        break;
    case "+":
        return "314";
        break;
    case "[":
        return "315";
        break;
    case "]":
        return "316";
        break;
    case "{":
        return "317";
        break;
    case "}":
        return "318";
        break;
    case "\\":
        return "319";
        break;
    case "|":
        return "320";
        break;
    case ";":
        return "321";
        break;
    case ":":
        return "322";
        break;
    case "'":
        return "323";
        break;
    case '"':
        return "323";
        break;
    case "`":
        return "324";
        break;
    case "~":
        return "325";
        break;
    case ",":
        return "326";
        break;
    case ".":
        return "327";
        break;
    case "<":
        return "238";
        break;
    case ">":
        return "239";
        break;
    case "/":
        return "240";
        break;
    case "?":
        return "241";
        break;
    default:
        return "404";
        break;
  }
}
```

and this is what I used to test it:

```
var date = new Date()
var message = encrypt(date.getHours.toString() + date.getMinutes.toString(), "This is an encrypted message!", "password");
alert(message.toString());
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: The notion of doing encryption on the client with JavaScript is fundamentally flawed. Use HTTPS if something needs to be sent securely to the server.

Comment: What, exactly, isn't working?

Comment: Do you have any console errors?

Comment: A jsfiddle showing what works and what does not would also be very appreciated...

Comment: scrappedcola's answer fixed my problem. To address what @robbmj said, I understand this isn't actually encryption. That's why I put it in quotes. I just thought i'd do something like this for fun. Also, here's the fiddle of the currently working code: http://jsfiddle.net/ecjkn8js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
var message = encrypt(date.getHours.toString() + date.getMinutes.toString(), "This is an encrypted message!", "password");
```

`getHours` and `getMinutes` are functions. You need to call them as such:

```
var message = encrypt(date.getHours().toString() + date.getMinutes().toString(), "This is an encrypted message!", "password");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4zxhzmw7/

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed that. I feel like such an idiot.

Comment: Ah it happens. A quick indicator is when you see function().... in the returned string. That's when you know you need to be searching for a missed function call.